# gcc -MMD omits local header files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, include, include-path

I'm invoking gcc with `-MMD`, and it lists some, but not all, the header files.

I've copied the FreeRTOS source into my project, include those files via `#include <...>`, and set the the `-I` path in the Makefile, and they appear in the `-MMD` output correctly.

But the standard `#include "...."` do not appear in the MMD output.

How can I solve (or debug) this?

---

## Updates

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` `gcc version 10.3.1 20210621` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Odd... My gcc omitted the system headers with that command (as the `gcc -v --help` implied. `gcc -MD` contained both system and local.  What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @Jason Updated with gcc ver.  `-MD` adds the system includes but still leaves out my project includes.  Perhaps my use of `#pragma once` is confusing it?

Comment: It still worked for me with `#pragma once` in a subdirectory with `-I` with native gcc and arm-none-eabi-gcc.  I am on Arch Linux, so my gccs are both 13.2.x.

Comment: Create a simple test project with one `.c` and one `.h` files and experiment with these, with `#pragma once` or without. If can't figure it out, post your test code, compile command and outputs here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm.... a simple project with a few trivial files is _not_ showing this behavior.  Trying to find a minimal example that replicates.

Comment: Are you using the same makefiles?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, I just used a command line invocation (no Makefile).  In the actual project, the Makefile is both large and dependent (i.e. if I remove some of the code files, then make complains), so I'm not sure how to go about finding the minimal parts of it.

Comment: I'd speculate that the problem is there. Unsilence the makefiles and examine the commands executed, maybe they don't get  the options you think they should.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.5.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), it is the location of the header on the filesystem, not the form of the `#include` directive, that determines whether a header is considered a system header for the purposes of `-MM` and `-MMD`.

Comment: Are you using the `-isystem` or `-idirafter` option?  Those muck with GCC's sense of which directories are system header directories.